# angular ng repeat nested json

Tags: angularjs, json, twig

I'm stuck wondering how to ng-repeat matches in this JSON object. I've tried various ways with some of them like this but with no luck.

```
<tr ng-repeat="game in game.competition.season.round.match">
  <td>{% verbatim %}{{ game["@attributes"].match_id }}{% endverbatim %}</td>
</tr>
```

When i use the whole object in ng-repeat i can get the value of the very first "@attributes" key but can't get to matches.

Any help is much appreciated.

```
[
  {
    "@attributes": {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "World",
      "last_updated": "2016-03-22 06:22:49"
    },
    "competition": {
      "@attributes": {
        "id": "19",
        "name": "Sony",
        "area_id": "203",
        "area_name": "USA",
        "last_updated": "2016-03-22 09:19:52"
      },
      "season": {
        "@attributes": {
          "season_id": "3628",
          "name": "2016",
          "start_date": "2016-03-21",
          "end_date": "2016-04-03",
          "draw_size": "64",
          "active": "yes",
        },
        "round": [
          {
            "@attributes": {
              "round_id": "21868",
              "title": "1/128 Final",
              "start_date": "2016-03-22",
              "end_date": "2016-03-26",
              "groups": "0",
              "last_updated": "2016-03-22 06:22:49"
            },
            "match": [
              {
                "@attributes": {
                  "match_id": "155624",
                  "official_start_date": "2016-03-22",
                  "official_start_time": "14:00:00",
                  "actual_start_date": "",
                  "actual_start_time": "",

                }
              },
              {
                "@attributes": {
                  "match_id": "155625",
                  "official_start_date": "2016-03-22",
                  "official_start_time": "14:00:00",
                  "actual_start_date": "",
                  "actual_start_time": "",
                  "winner": "yet unknown",
                  "score_A": "",
                  "score_B": "",
                  "status": "Fixture",
                  "drawposition": "38",
                  "person_A_id": "14688",
                }
              },
              {
                "@attributes": {
                  "match_id": "155626",
                  "official_start_date": "2016-03-22",
                  "official_start_time": "14:00:00",
                  "actual_start_date": "",
                  "actual_start_time": "",
                  "winner": "yet unknown",
                  "score_A": "",
                  "score_B": "",
                }
              },
              {
                "@attributes": {
                  "match_id": "155627",
                  "official_start_date": "2016-03-22",
                  "official_start_time": "14:00:00",
                  "actual_start_date": "",
                  "actual_start_time": "",
                  "winner": "yet unknown",
                  "score_A": "",
                }
              },
              {
                "@attributes": {
                  "match_id": "155628",
                  "official_start_date": "2016-03-22",
                  "official_start_time": "14:00:00",
                  "actual_start_date": "",
                  "actual_start_time": "",
                  "winner": "yet unknown",
                  "score_A": "",
                  "score_B": "",
                }
              },
              {
                "@attributes": {
                  "match_id": "155629",
                  "official_start_date": "2016-03-22",
                  "official_start_time": "14:00:00",
                  "actual_start_date": "",
                  "actual_start_time": "",
                  "winner": "yet unknown",
                  "score_A": "",
                  "score_B": "",
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: have you tried removing the @ in the attributes and trying it again?

Comment: What is the desired result?

Comment: @zeroflagL Desired result is to repeat through match node

Comment: @Manu Anthony yes, i've tried that but with no success

Comment: Try removing @ and then `<tr ng-repeat="game as game.attributes in game.competition.season.round.match"> <td>{% verbatim %}{{ game.match_id }}{% endverbatim %}</td>
</tr> `

Comment: @Manu nope, it didn't work :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

should be like this,

```
  <table>
    <tr ng-repeat="game in game[0].competition.season.round[0].match">
  <td>{% verbatim %}{{ game["@attributes"].match_id }}{% endverbatim %}</td>
</tr>

  </table>
```

Comment: sorry actually like this.  you have multiple arrays there within each other.

Comment: sorry, cached version was with me. And could you explain why round[0] instead of just round? Thank you

Comment: round is also an array itself so you need to specify which array member you are looking for.  if you make it an object then your notation will work.  same goes for game array

Comment: ofcourse, i missed the [ bracket. thanks a bunch z.a.